# $\mu^\lambda = 2^\lambda$ for infinite $\mu$ and $\lambda$

Tags: cardinals

The original question is (from Mathematical Logic, A course with Exercises):

Assume Axiom of Choice, let $a$ and $b$ be 2 infinite sets with $\text{card}(a)=\lambda$ and $\text{card}(b)=\mu$. Assume $\lambda > \mu$. Let $g$ be an injective mapping from $b$ to $a$.

Determine the cardinality of  $\{f\in b^a: \text{card}(f^{-1}(b))= \lambda\}$

I know this is the cardinality of $\mu^\lambda$, but the solution manual says $\mu^\lambda = 2^\lambda$. I think I have missed some lemma. How to prove it?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: $$2^\lambda\le\mu^\lambda\le(2^\mu)^\lambda=2^{\mu\lambda}=2^\lambda$$

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an infinite cardinal then $2^\lambda=\mu^\lambda\iff2\le\mu\le2^\lambda$.

Comment: Right. Thanks! You may post it so I can accept it as an answer.